# Kafka Operations on Windowed KTables

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb, windowed

I would like to do some further operations on a windowed KTable. To give some background, I have a topic with data in the form of: `{clientId, txTimestamp, txAmount}`. From this topic, I have created a stream, partitioned by clientId with the underlying topic timestamp equal to the txTimestamp event field. Starting from this stream, I want to aggregate the number of transactions per clientId in every 1 hour windows. This is done with something similar to the following:
`CREATE TABLE transactions_per_client WITH (kafka_topic='transactions_per_client_topic') AS SELECT clientId, COUNT(*) AS transactions_per_client, WINDOWSTART AS window_start, WINDOWEND AS window_end FROM transactions_stream WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 HOURS) GROUP BY clientId;`

The aggregations work as expected and yield values similar to:

| ClientId | Transactions_per_client | windowsStart | WindowEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 8 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 24 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 19 | 3 | 4 |

What I want to do now is further process this table to add a column that represents the difference in number of transactions per client between 2 adjacent windows for the same client. For the previous table, that would be something like this:

| ClientId | Transactions_per_client | windowsStart | WindowEnd | Deviation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 8 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 24 | 2 | 3 | 12 |
| 1 | 19 | 3 | 4 | -5 |

What would be the best way to achieve this (either using kafka streams or ksql)? I tried to use the User Defined Aggregation functions to try to create this column but it cannot be applied to a KTable, only to a KStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for future reference, the official answer at this time (April 2022) is that it cannot be done in kafka-streams through a DSL as "Windowed-TABLE are kind of a “dead end” in ksqlDB atm, and also for Kafka Streams, you cannot really use the DSL to further process the data" (answer on Confluent forum here: https://forum.confluent.io/t/aggregations-on-windowed-ktables/4340). The suggestion there is to use the Processor API, which indeed can be pretty straightforward to implement. At a high level pseudocode, it would be something like this:

```
topology.addSource(NAME_OF_SOURCE_IN_THE_NEW_TOPOLOGY, 
timeWindowedDeserializer, LongDeserializer, SOURCE_TOPIC -> the topic with the windowed KTable);

topology.addProcessor(
                NAME_OF_PROCESSOR_IN_THE_NEW_TOPOLOGY,
                () -> new Aggregator(storeName),
                NAME_OF_SOURCE_IN_THE_NEW_TOPOLOGY);
StoreBuilder storeBuilder = keyValueStoreBuilder for the timeWindowedSerde and a Long serde for value;

topology.addStateStore(storeBuilder, NAME_OF_PROCESSOR_IN_THE_NEW_TOPOLOGY);

topology.addSink(
                NAME_OF_SINK_IN_THE_NEW_TOPOLOGY,
                sinkTopic,
                timeWindowedSerializer,
                Serializer for the new structure -> POJO that contains the deviation field,
                NAME_OF_PROCESSOR_IN_THE_NEW_TOPOLOGY);
```

The aggregator in the previous section is a org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.Processor implementation that is keeping track of the values it has seen and is able to retrieve the previous seen value for a given key.
Again, at a high level it would be something similar to this:

```
Long previousTransactionAggregate = kvStore.get(previousWindow);

long deviation;
if (previousTransactionAggregate != null) {
      deviation = kafkaRecord.value() - previousTransactionAggregate;
} else {
     deviation = 0L;
}
kvStore.put(kafkaRecord.key(), kafkaRecord.value());
Record<Windowed<Long>, TransactionPerNumericKey> newRecord =
                new Record<>(
                        kafkaRecord.key(),
                        new TransactionPerNumericKey(
                                kafkaRecord.key().key(), kafkaRecord.value(), deviation),
                        kafkaRecord.timestamp());

context.forward(newRecord);
```

TransactionPerNumericKey in the previous section is the name of the structure for the enhanced windowed aggregation (containing the deviation value)